# Interview questions at amazon in unix

Tags: shell, unix

1.Count multiple occurences of your name in a file.. and your name is occurring multiple times in a line.

2.Write a regular expression to retrieve “Ravi-10” from the file. And print only  the name “Ravi-10” (complete line should not be printed) .

3.In a log file you have date in yyyy mm dd hh:mi:ss format. Retrive those dates where time is between 19:10:00 to 19:20:00

Comment: Are you _in a middle_ of a UNIX interview and post the message with your mobile to get the result? : )

Comment: This was the question asked in amazon interview which i was not able to answer so please let me know

Answer (score 6):

I hope I get the job if I answer properly...

1.Count multiple occurences of your name in a file.. and your name is occurring multiple times in a line.

```
grep -o "your_name" file | wc -w
```

2.Write a regular expression to retrieve “Ravi-10” from the file. And print only the name “Ravi-10” (complete line should not be printed) .

```
grep -o "Ravi-10" file
```

3.In a log file you have date in yyyy mm dd hh:mi:ss format. Retrive those dates where time is between 19:10:00 to 19:20:00

```
awk '{if (($4 ~ "19:1[0-9]") || ($4 ~ "19:20")) {print}}' your_file
```